# AS3 MXML onInvoke and applicationComplete order

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, command-line, air

I would like to get the command line arguments prior to `applicationComplete` occurs                       `applicationComplete="init()`. In `init()` I would like to use those command line arguments, but it appears the `onInvoke` is happening after `init()`. Currently I have `onInvoke`  and `applicationComplete` in my `main.mxml` in the following order.

```xml
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   xmlns:noxaos="com.someplace.*"
                   xmlns:skins="skins.*"
                   invoke="onInvoke(event)"
                   applicationComplete="init()"
                   width="400"
                   height="600">
```

Comment: Are you building an AIR Desktop application?  Or a mobile application?

Comment: AIR Desktop application

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the order of execution by changing the property order.

Actually the `invoke` Event is normally triggered *before* the `applicationComplete` Event, but the `WindowedApplication` class queues it until the window is added to the stage.

If you need to respond to the `invoke` event at an earlier stage, then you'll have to subscribe to the dispatching object directly, which would be the `NativeApplication` class.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#event:invoke

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, invokeHandler);
```

However, there is no *guarantee* that the `invoke` event is dispatched earlier, so in order to avoid possible race conditions, you should only process further after the `invoke` has been dispatched.

You could manage this by for example subscribing to the `invoke` Event directly in the `applicationComplete` handler, and move all your stuff from there into the `invoke` handler. This should work fine since the `invoke` events are being queued and will fire directly after subscribing.

Comment: Thanks for the information. There was a thought about having the `InvokeHandler` register after `applicationComplete` and proceed after being called with the init of the application. Wasn't sure if that was a good practice.